# Does center bore difference of 0.06mm matter?

Tags: wheels, volvo, winter, tolerance, v40

Recently I ordered a set of alloy wheels for my **Volvo V40 MY 2015** which has a center bore **63.4**. I noticed only now that there is a slight difference in the center bore (everything else is precisely correct) in the specs - they are **63.34**, so the center bore of the alloys is 0.06mm (or 60 micrometers) *smaller*.

The question is will this matter when mounting the wheels? I suspect rust, imperfections, etc. can create such difference too.

Secondly, if mounting won't be a problem, can removing be a problem? I remember dealing with a stuck wheel in the past.

I tried to search for any tolerances, experience, etc. but all I found was this [comment in the video suggesting to use sandpaper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqRF_n9laZA&lc=Ugi5xMZ-eoNFY3gCoAEC.8Nwj_GfyoRb8RHRWUNBWKP). I would return the wheels and try to find another set, but nothing is available at such size at the moment, and I need to switch to winter set asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take into account the width of a human hair is [~.04-.12mm](http://www.schwarzkopf.com/en/hair-care/split-ends/hair-dictionary.html), your .04mm is not a lot of difference. If you take some fine grit sandpaper (in the 200-300 grit arena) or a Scotchbrite pad and run it around the inside of the center bore three or four times for each wheel, they should fit onto the hub without issue and not stick when you try to pull them off. You shouldn't have to worry about centering as the lug nuts into the lug holes will do this for you when you torque them down. This kind of thing happens all the time. Really, it isn't much to worry about (with a little elbow grease, that is). If you are worried about slip or what have you, it's not the center portion which keeps the wheels in place on the hub, but the interface between the wheel and the hub itself. As long as the lugs are torqued correctly, you'll not have any issues with it (which is the same for any wheel on any car out there).

Comment: Is elbow grease still available ?  :) :)

Comment: @SolarMike - You'll find it down the aisle with the blinker fluid :o)

Comment: You may be joking, but I've never heard the "elbow grease" idiom and had to look it up thinking it's used to "prevent the wheels from sticking" :) Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 along with the compression powder, bags of sparks, sets of plug gaps and sets of dwell angles - mind you, lots of so-called mechanics won't recognise dwell angles since most petrol engines are electronic ignition... Remember sending one apprentice for an "interior light beam setter" - wouldn't speak to us for days after that one!